SwiftUI context menu scroll broken when view changes
I have a view that changes with a timer and I want to be able to long press that view and show a context menu. However the scroll on the context menu seems to be broken?
I am on ios 18 and xcode 16

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var number = 0
  @State var timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.25, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text(number.formatted())
        .font(.largeTitle)
      Text("Long press me")
      Text("Notice context menu cannot scroll down")
    }
    .padding()
    .background {
      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0)
        .fill(Color(uiColor: .secondarySystemBackground))
    }
    .contextMenu {
      ForEach(0 ..< 100) { index in
        Button {
          print("option \(index)")
        } label: {
          Label("Option \(index)", systemImage: "globe")
        }
      }
    }
    .onReceive(timer) { t in
      number += 1
    }
  }
}


Is this a bug in swiftUI? In my real application I want the context menu to be able to switch the kind of data the user is viewing and all data is changing real time

Whenever State value changes the body of the view is called to update the views.
Since your code is a single view the init of every view is called and compared.(All the buttons in context)
You can move the buttons to separate view to improve performance
.contextMenu {
    ContextListView()
}

struct ContextListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0 ..< 100) { index in
            Button {
              print("option \(index)")
            } label: {
              Label("Option \(index)", systemImage: "globe")
            }
        }
    }
}

Please check the answers for this question for more understanding SwiftUI Text, changing the text with @State property causing whole view to re-render

even though this fixes the issue I still feel its a bug in swiftUI. The scroll view state should not reset. By this logic, states changes within a any scroll view would bring the scroll view back to the top. Which doesn't make sense. Another thing that seems like a bug is that moving view builder code to a separate struct should not change behavior. I understand it may make it more efficient but who says it will change behavior?

@Abhi, can you please mention which state changes makes scrollview reset?

hey Immanuel when the context menu is visible, changing @State number will reset the scroll of the context menu to the top

the scroll resets, if you try to scroll as soon as the context menu appears. but works normally if scrolled after minor delay

Did you the try the inline version? Moving the context menu to a separate view fixes the scroll.  However the scroll constantly resets for me with the context menu inline. I'm also on ios 18

if a view identity changes new view is created. try scroll in this List {
ContextListView()
}.id(number). so something similar is happening in context menu
